# Mysql dynamic column with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem how to store some data in mysql. 
I have website which when link is pressed pass some data to php file which read this data with get and write in database(mysql). I'm passing campaign_id and unknown number of parameters.

```
http://domain.com/somefile.php?campaignid=1&parameter1=sometext1&parameter2=sometext2&parameter3=sometext3,....etc..
```

I don't know actual number of parameters because user make them in some sort of cms. The problem I'm facing is how to store them in database. I was thinking to make it like this below but i'm not sure if it's the right and the most effective way:

```
Combinations Table
-combination_id (Primary key and auto increment)
-campaign_id
-parameter1
-parameter2
-parameter3
-parameter4
-parameter5
-parameter6
-parameter7
-parameter8
-parameter9
-parameter10
```

In this example I assume that user will not add/use more than 10 parameters(which I think is lame, but I can't get better solution)

Also if I use this design I assume I need to check in this file where is get them from passing and write to database, if each parameter exist(if it was passed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to normalize your schema.

Assume the following tables:

```
Entity: id, campaign_id, other fields.
Parameter: id, entityId, parameterValue.
```

This is a Many-to-One relation.

Comment: Technically I agree, and if I am to use the database purist view, that's the way to do it. But it depends on how the data are to be used - some use cases gets so much more difficult with a normalized schema using a non-normalized schema may be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

What About storing all the parameters as json in one table row?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

- combination_id (primary key auto increment)
- campaign_id ( indexed / foreign key / can't be unique!)
- param_name
- param_value

You'd have to create an entry for every parameter you're getting, but you could theoretically add a thousand parameters or more.

Might not be the fastest method though and can be a bit hard to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the kind of data nosql databases are made for... At least, trying to force it into a sql database always ends up as some kind of kludge. (been there done it...)

as far as I can see, you have three different ways of storing it:

1. As you proposed. Probably the easiest way to handle it and also probably the most efficient. But, at the moment you get 11 parameters you are in for major problems...
2. Make a parameter table - parameter_id, - campaign_id parameter (possible parameter name if it matters) - this gives you total flexibility - but everything else, ecept for searching for single values gets more difficult,
3. Combine the parameters and store them all in a text or varchar field. This is probably even more efficient than 1, except for searching for single parameter values.

   And if  I may add
4. Use a database system with an array type, eg postgresql

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the actual number of parameters that will come through url, there is a best option to store the infinite number of values for a **campaign_id**.

For that you can create multiple rows in the table. Like,

```
insert into table_name values(<campaign_id>,<parameter1>,<sometext>)
insert into table_name values(<campaign_id>,<parameter2>,<sometext>)
insert into table_name values(<campaign_id>,<parameter3>,<sometext>)
insert into table_name values(<campaign_id>,<parameter4>,<sometext>)
```

Assuming the **campaign_id** is unique in url.